# Copy of element using java XSLT looses namespace with output html (not for first element)

Tags: java, xslt, namespaces

I have the following XML

```
<root>
  <a>test</a>
  <b xmlns="bns">test</b>
  <a>test</a>
  <b xmlns="bns">test</b>
  <a>test</a>
</root>
```

and this XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If i apply the XSL to the XML using Java the namespace of the second b-tag is removed:

```
<root>
  <a>test</a>
  <b xmlns="bns">test</b>
  <a>test</a>
  <b>test</b>
  <a>test</a>
</root>
```

I noticed that this only happens for output method html. Can anybody tell me why and what i can do about it?

Comment: I have tested with Xalan 2.7.1 at http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rM8 but can't reproduce the problem. So tell us more details as to which XSLT processor you use with Java, respectively which version of Java if it is the built-in processor, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using "OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)" (Version 1.7.0_65). The used transformer class is com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
. I did some further testing and the error only occurs in output mode html and not in xml output mode.

Comment: Java 1.7 would allow you to use Saxon 9 and XSLT 2.0 which hopefully is in a better state than the internalized Xalan that the JDK has.

Comment: Yes it would probably be but i would like to to it without external libraries. I only get the error if i transform it from "within a java application" if i use the command line "java <JARs of JRE> org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process <XSL/IN/OU>" it works fine.

Comment: I am not really familiar with details about Xalan, I know it basically has two XSLT 1.0 implementations, one that interprets XSLT, one that compiles it, I think `xsltc` is the compiler, so you would first need to make sure the application code and the command line use the same implementation `xsltc`. If there are still differences, then it could simply be caused by different versions of the internalized Xalan in the JDK and the one Apache offers. I think the Xalan Java project on Apache got some minor update recently, so maybe there you can find more expertise than here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I added Xalan 2.7.1 directly to the classpath and it works now. So there has to be a problem with the internal version of Xalan. I didn't really want to do that but i don't think i can work around that bug. Thanks for your help anyway.